# Use an element's text for parent heading's ID value

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my page I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="Module-item"><!-- list -->

    <div class="AnchorContainer" id="">
        <h1>
            <span class="InsertAsAnchor">Services</span>
        </h1>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

HTML piece is a list and therefore is more common on a page with different types of content.
What I want is this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    //loop trough entire page .Module-item .AnchorContainer h1 span
    //if span contains text, take value and use it as ID for h1, but this could also be H2,H3,H4,H5 and H6
    //and if span contains text with spaces, remove the spaces so 'Our Services' becomes 'Ourservices'

});
```

I hope someone can show me how this can be done on a correct way,

Comment: Everything you wanna do is easily searchable. Try something, show us what's not working!

Comment: The JSfiddle is coming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're new I'll cut you some slack. Try this:

```
$('.Module-item h1 > span, .Module-item h2 > span, .Module-item h3 > span')
  .each(function() {
    var myText = $(this).text().replace(' ','');
    $(this).parent().attr('id', myText);
});
```

- http://api.jquery.com/each
- http://api.jquery.com/text
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

In the future, please do take a crack at it, first.

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing the links. It will surely help!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it.

http://jsfiddle.net/f7jhtd4x/

```
var moduleSpan = $('.module-item span');
$.each(moduleSpan, function(key, value){
    var span = $(this);
    if(span.text()) span.closest('.anchor-container').attr('id', span.text().replace(/ /g,''));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$('.Module-item > .AnchorContainer').find('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6').attr('id', function() {
     var sp = $('>span:first', this);
     if( sp.length === 1 || sp.text().trim().length > 0 ) {
       return sp.text().trim().replace(/ /g,'');
     }
});
```

```js
$('.Module-item > .AnchorContainer').find('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6').attr('id', function() {
     var sp = $('>span:first', this);
     if( sp.length === 1 || sp.text().trim().length > 0 ) {
       return sp.text().trim().replace(/ /g,'');
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Module-item"><!-- list -->

    <div class="AnchorContainer" id="">
        <h1>
            <span class="InsertAsAnchor"> Services </span>
        </h1>
        <h3>
            <span class="InsertAsAnchor"></span>
        </h3>
        <h5>
            <span class="InsertAsAnchor">Our Very Many Services </span>
        </h5>
        <h6>
            <span class="InsertAsAnchor">  Their Services</span>
        </h6>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: this als works, thanks for your effort!

Comment: No problem. I just updated it to make it shorter and easier to understand.